# Sony Xperia E6833 4K Display, Xamarin's Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi returns incorrect value

Tags: android, xamarin.ios

Cpecifications for E6833 says that this device has a screen with resolution of 4K 2160 x 3840 pixels (~ 801 PPI pixel density). However, Xamarin Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi returns a value Android.Util.DisplayMetricsDensity.Xxhigh  corresponding to HD display, instead of Android.Util.DisplayMetricsDensity.Xxxhigh, corresponding to 4K display. Who knows - Why?

Comment: I have no access to that device and I have also never used xamarin, but I know that some 4k devices normally run just in FullHD and use 4k just for some special apps. So this might explain why you get a lower value.

Comment: May be. Thank you.